# Two Bootstrap buttons aligned to the right in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get two buttons to stay when possible one next to other aligned at the right side of the panel.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7q73o59/3/) with my current solution.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">my panel title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="#" class="form">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-1">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-1">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you have added wrong fiddle

Comment: Lol thanks, i'll fix it soon

Comment: It's been already fixed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put both buttons in a column (`col-*-*`) and use `text-right` class to parent div.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">my panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="#" class="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works responsive.. perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Update your

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button>
</div>
```

to

```
<span class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button>
</span>
<span class="col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button>
</span>
```

Reason being is that spans can sit side by side whereas divs cannot

Comment: Your solution is correct but since vivoconunxino is using boostrap, i guess he could simply wrapp the 2 columns in a "row"

Comment: In fact, your solution helped. In real code I have a `<div class='dropdown'...` instead of a button1. So I mixed your both solutions to make it work, changed to a span and pushed both elements into a single column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your row class to :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-1" style="text-align: right; padding: 0px; ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1">button1</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left: 0px; ">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2" type="submit">button2</button> 
    </div> 
</div>
```